# strcpy() unusual behaviour in C

Tags: c, c-strings, strcpy

so I decided to test out how strcpy() works and while reading the Linux Programmer's Manual. I came across the definition of strcpy

> The  strings  may  not overlap, and the destination string dest must be
> large enough to receive the copy.

So from this I can probably concur that the size of the destination string should be equal to or greater than the source string.
But when I try to run the followng program in CLion, I get a smash stacking error

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main()
{  
   char str1[7], str2[3] = "Hiy";
   strcpy(str1, str2);
   printf("%s", str1);
}
```

Here the size of str1 well exceeds the size of str2. In the ideal case, the strcpy should copy "Hiy" to str1 and then the print function should display "Hiy" but still I am getting the same smash stacking error. 
 I think it may have something to do with str2 having no null character (since I have filled  the entire character array with characters) but I'm not sure. Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Comment: "still I am getting an error." Which one? Please quote/show the effect and contrast it against what you expect.

Comment: @Yunnosch ok will edit

Comment: Please explain how you expect `srtcpy()` to determine the length of the source string, in order to stop copying.

Comment: `str2[3] = "Hiy";` you don't allocate enough space for the string. `str` can only store a string of maximum 2 characters

Comment: What happens if you try `printf("<%s>", str2);
   printf("<%s>", str1);`?

Comment: What are the addresses of the two arrays? Actually, what is their difference?

Comment: @Yunnosch The code won't run with the strcpy() snippet in it (same smash stacking error) but the code runs if I remove it. By using `printf("<%s>, str2);` I get the ouput as <Hiy�>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the null character is attached end of the string you can't store
`str2[3] = "Hiy";` because array str2 has only 3 slots and your string has 4 characters including empty string char at end.Replace that with `str2[4] = "Hiy";`
Then you'll be able to have your intended output.

Comment: Thank you this does the job. I understood my mistake now.

Comment: It compiles and stores the three characters without the trailing \0, so str2 is just an array of three characters, not a valid C string.

Comment: Also worth looking into [strncpy](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/).